# Delayed_job : defining time

Tags: delayed-job

So I'm trying to figure out how to do this cleanly. Trying to keep the example simple lets say I have an object, `MyMailMeeting` in which I define two times that I want to send two different emails to people in a meeting.

In my `MyMailMeeting` model, I want to define both methods (rather than having their own delayed job class), but I need to have those methods see the times defined within the object in order to know when to send.

```
def send_first
  ... do stuff
end
handle_asynchronously :send_first, :run_at => Proc.new { send_first_time }
```

Problem is that according to the [documentation](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job), `send_first_time` needs to be a class method, and want it to be an instance method so that I can see the times defined by the user.

How do I do this? Or do I just need to create two separate Delayed_job classes and do something like this:

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue(SendFirstJob.new, :run_at => send_first_time)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the second method. Though it isn't as time sensitive as I would like.

If anyone has an answer on how to get `send_first_time` to be a variable that is based on user input, I'll gladly accept it as the right answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that handle_asynchronously passes the object into Procs for its attributs so:

```
handle_asynchronously :send_first, :run_at => Proc.new { |obj| obj.send_first_time }
```

You can always roll your own async wrapper

```
def send_first_async(*args)
  delay(:run_at => send_first_time).send_first(*args)
end
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. There are no examples of delay taking a time option in the gem's README/wiki and this answer helped me figure out a short-n-sweet way to schedule the task in future instead of using the ugly - handle_asynchronously.